# Add a class dependent on number of selected option

Tags: jquery

I have a select-box used a lot of times on a page.

```
<div class="some-div">
    <a class="maybe">Maybe</a>
    <select class="selectclass">
        <option>Maybe</option>
        <option>Yes</option>
        <option>No</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

How could I using jQuery add a class to 'a' element dependent on the number of the selected option? The class must be taken not from the value because the site is multilingual, but from the number of the option: 'maybe' for 1st, 'yes' for 2nd and 'no' for the 3rd. The select is used many times on the page so it should apply only for the one which is in action.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated - As according to OP's Requirements

Are you trying to do as something did in this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/AuY6S/)

**jQuery:**

```
$('.selectclass').change(function(){

    var number = $(this).val();
    var value = $("option^[value=" + number + "]").text();

    $(this).parent().find('a').html(value);    
    $(this).parent().find('a').attr('class', 'opt' + number);

});​
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="some-div">
    <a class="opt1">Maybe</a>
    <select class="selectclass">
        <option value="1">Maybe</option>
        <option value="2">Yes</option>
        <option value="3">No</option>
    </select>
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```
.opt1{ color:blue; }
.opt2{ color:green; }
.opt3{ color:red; }​
```

Comment: Many thanks. Yes, exactly! But as i mentioned - site is multilingual and the value might be on other language but the class must remain.. So how to track on option by its number?

Answer (score 1):

First of all change your HTML to use option "value" attribute, so you won't care about the multilanguage architecture.

```
<div class="some-div">
<a class="maybe">Maybe</a>
<select class="selectclass">
    <option value="1">Maybe</option>
    <option value="2">Yes</option>
    <option value="3">No</option>
</select>
```

Bind to your ddl change method and use jquery to find the value of your ddl.

```
$('.selectclass').bind("change", function() {  
var option = $(this).val();
if (option == 1)
{
//your code
}
else if...
});
```

Comment: We are definitely singing from the same hymn sheet!

Answer (score 1):

### HTML

Add some values to your options...

```
<div class="some-div">
    <a class="maybe">Maybe</a>
    <select class="selectclass">
        <option value="maybe">Maybe</option>
        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="no">No</option>
    </select>
</div>​​​​​​
```

### Javascript (jQuery)

The selectors will have to be made more specific in real code to avoid conflicts...

```
// add a `change` event to the select element
​$("select").on("change",function(){
    // get the value of the select element
    var val = $(this).val()
    // remove all classes from the `a` tag  and add the
    // recently got value as a class of the `a` tag
    $("a").removeClass().addClass(val)
})​​​​​​​​​
```

### CSS

Just for testing...

​

```
.no{
    color: red;
}
.yes{
    color: green;
}

.maybe{
    color: orange;
}
​
```

### Demo

Pre baked demo can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/uBCJd/

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the index of the selected option and changes the link's class and text
    ​

```
$(".selectclass").live("change",function(){
    var index = $(this).children("option:selected").index() + 1;
    $(this).parent().find('a').text(index+':'+$(this).val());
    $(this).parent().find('a').attr('class',index);
});​
```